# Given |A\B| = |B\A|, prove |A|=|B| and provide 2 sets (A and B) such that |A| = |B| but |A\B| is not the same as |B\A|

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Part A : Given |A\B| = |B\A|, prove |A|=|B|
Part B : Provide 2 sets (A and B) such that |A| = |B| but |A\B| is not the same as |B\A|

**Part A:**

Let A,B be sets. Given that |A\B| = |B\A| then |A|=|B|

Hint was given to us "find a one to one and onto function between A and B". but am struggling to do so."

I started with a bidirectional inclusion, i.e first show |A| <= |B| then vis-versa, as we only care about the cardinality and not the elements inside, I wasn't sure how to proceed.
i.e let A have n elements, since |A\B| = |B\A|, B also needs to have at least n elements...

**Part B:**

For the 2nd part, after testing a lot of examples I came up with this: Let A = $\mathbb{Z}$, B = $\mathbb{N}$

|A| = |B| = $\aleph_0$

But A\B = Only the negative integers, |A\B| = $\aleph_0$

B\A = $\emptyset$, |B\A| = 0

Which clearly have different cardinalities

Is my logic flawed, and are there other examples (not so similar)?

Comment: $\vert A\setminus B \vert = \vert A \vert - \vert A\cap B \vert\ $ and $\ \vert B\setminus A \vert = \vert B \vert - \vert B\cap A \vert.\ $ If $\vert A\setminus B \vert = \vert B\setminus A \vert $ then it is straightforward to conclude that $\ \vert A \vert = \vert B \vert.$

Comment: @Prem was a "hint" that was given on the same exam

Comment: That hint is for Part B , where we have to make the Sets & we will know the elements , thus we may make the functions too. Part A will have no such necessity.

Comment: [ +1 ] You have come up with a great Example for Part 2 !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **Part A is true ONLY when $A$ & $B$ are finite.**

[image: PART A]

In the Pictorial Proof ( Venn Diagram ) , where I am using numbers $x,y,z$ to indicate Set Sizes ( not elements ) , we can easily see that :
$|A|=x+y$
$|B|=z+y$

We are given $|A \setminus B|=x=z=|B \setminus A|$
Hence $x+y=z+y$ ( adding $y$ )

$|A|=x+y=z+y=|B|$

This type of calculation works when we have finite numbers.

### **Part B will require $A$ & $B$ infinite.**

Let $A$ be some arbitrary infinite Set ( Eg Integers , rationals , irrationals , Naturals )

Let $C$ be some finite Set of unrelated elements , eg $C=\{ Apple , Orange , Newton , Atom \}$

Let $B=A \cup C$

The Sets $A$ & $B$ will work.

$|A|=|B|$

$|A \setminus B|=0$
$|B \setminus A|=|C|$

Comment: Appreciate the prompt response!